# ReactJs SyntaxError with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]Below code shows syntax error in ReactJs component:

```
(that.props.actionType == "opinion")
?
{that.state._CmtCnt?<ViewAnswer isFullView={that.props.isFullView?true:false} />:null}
:
{that.state._CmtCnt?<ViewComment isFullView={that.props.isFullView?true:false} />:null}
```

Comment: Probably because you have a syntax error. Without more context, this is going to be difficult to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Syntax is:

> condition? expression1 : expression2

This is because you are using `{}` with expression1 and expression2, remove that, `{}` is required when we want to put JS expressions inside JSX. The way you are using, it means you are trying to return an object and error is because key is not valid.

Write it like this:

```
(that.props.actionType == "opinion") ?
    (that.state._CmtCnt?<ViewAnswer isFullView={that.props.isFullView?true:false} />:null)
:
    (that.state._CmtCnt?<ViewComment isFullView={that.props.isFullView?true:false} />:null)
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank, By changing of bracket from {} to () it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use normal parenthesis for grouping. Braces work only within jsx expressions.

```
that.props.actionType == "opinion"
  ? (that.state._CmtCnt ? <ViewAnswer isFullView={that.props.isFullView} /> : null)
//  ^                                                                             ^
  : (that.state._CmtCnt ? <ViewComment isFullView={that.props.isFullView} /> : null)
//  ^                                                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write easier to understand code rather than complex nested terinary with little changes between them - all you choose is pick up a component to use, so move that up and you end up with easier to read code with less logic inside JSX

```
const Renderer = that.props.actionType == "opinion" ? ViewAnswer : ViewComment
// ...

{that.state._CmtCnt && <Renderer isFullView={!!that.props.isFullView} />}
// or
{that.state._CmtCnt ? 
  <Renderer isFullView={!!that.props.isFullView} /> :
  null
}
```

not sure why you are using `that` either - aliases for context such as `self` or `that` are a bit out of date, you tend to want to keep context to your instances and bind correctly