# What is wrong here? Component with ternary inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, ternary

```
    export const Date = ({ startDate, endDate, displayInUserTime }) => {
    const parsedStartDate = moment.utc(startDate).format("ll");
    const parsedEndDate = moment.utc(endDate).format("ll");
    const parsedLocalStartDate = moment(startDate).format("ll");
    const parsedLocalEndDate = moment(endDate).format("ll");

    return (
        <Content column className="col-1">
            {displayInUserTime ? 
            (<div>{parsedStartDate}</div>
            {parsedStartDate !== parsedEndDate && <div>{parsedEndDate}</div>}) 
            :
            (<div>{parsedLocalStartDate}</div>
            {parsedLocalStartDate !== parsedLocalEndDate && <div>{parsedLocalEndDate}</div>})}
        </Content>
    );
};
```

Error:
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

33 |          {displayInUserTime ? 
  34 |          ({parsedStartDate}

> 35 |          {parsedStartDate !== parsedEndDate && {parsedEndDate}}) 
>        |          ^
>     36 |          :
>     37 |          ({parsedLocalStartDate}
>     38 |          {parsedLocalStartDate !== parsedLocalEndDate && {parsedLocalEndDate}})}

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266276/reactjs-syntaxerror-with-ternary-operator

Comment: you can return only one element for each condition state. Ex: {  X==1 ?  (<div>TRUE</div>) :  (<div>FALSE</div>)  }.                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                     
You can't use like {  X==1 ?  (<div>TRUE1</div><div>TRUE2</div>) :  (<div>FALSE1</div><div>FALSE2</div>) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning multiple elements in the `{}` simplified code looks like `bool?<one/><two/>:<three/><four/>` the other answer changes the code to if statements but you could wrap your ternary in a React.Fragment: `bool?<><one/><two/></>:<><three/><four/></>`

Your code could be:

```
<Content column className="col-1">
  {displayInUserTime ? (
    <>
      <div>{parsedStartDate}</div>
      {parsedStartDate !== parsedEndDate && (
        <div>{parsedEndDate}</div>
      )}
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <div>{parsedLocalStartDate}</div>
      {parsedLocalStartDate !== parsedLocalEndDate && (
        <div>{parsedLocalEndDate}</div>
      )}
    </>
  )}
</Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making mind games with ternary operator how about you use if else statement

```
  let startDate = null;

  if(displayInUserTime) {
    startDate = <>
      <div>{parsedStartDate}</div>
      {parsedStartDate !== parsedEndDate && <div>{parsedEndDate}</div>}
    </>;
  }else {
    startDate = <>
      <div>{parsedLocalStartDate}</div>
      {parsedLocalStartDate !== parsedLocalEndDate && <div>{parsedLocalEndDate}</div>}
    </>
  }

  return (
        <Content column className="col-1">
            {startDate}
        </Content>
    );
```